# How to share socket instance over multiple files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to use socket instance from multiple files. I have written my socket connection code in App.js File. Which looks like as follow

```
var socketCode = require('../api/sockets/socketCode.js');

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socketCode(io, socket);
}
```

Now my `socketCode.js` File looks like follow

```
module.exports = (io, socket) => {
  test: function(data) {
    console.log("io", io, "\n", "socket", socket)
    return io;
  }
}
```

Now I want to call `test` function from another file let's say from `user.js`.

My `user.js` looks like :

```
var socketCode = require('../api/sockets/socketCode.js')();
console.log(socketCode.test);
```

The aim is to keep separate socket code and controllers and other code. Whenever I want to emit some event/message from controller. I just want to call function inside `socetCode.js` Which should emit the socket event.

How can i call `test` living inside `socketCode.js` file from `user.js`. and it should print/log `io` object.

I could not find any proper file structure along with socket. I am using express js.

Comment: You did not express what your actual problem/question is?

Comment: How to call `test` function from `users.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already figured out how to create the module which exports a named function in `socketCode.js`:

```
module.exports = (io, socket) => {
  test: function(data) {
    console.log("io", io, "\n", "socket", socket)
    return io;
  }
}
```

You would simply need to import this module somewhere else:

```
var io = "your io object";
var socket = "your socket object";
var socket = require('../api/sockets/socketCode.js')(io, socket);
socket.test();
```

A quick explanation: You are exporting an object with functions as properties. So each function can be considered as member of your imported object.

Comment: i have tried, it does not work. It throws an error `test` is not a function. I have also tried `socket.test` that also not worked.

And you wrote `var socket = require('../api/sockets/socketCode.js')(io, socket);`
But suppose if i want to require it in any controller files. I would not have `io` and `socket` instance there.

Comment: @MalikLakhani I am sorry, your module is expecting two parameters (io and socket) which you have to pass into it. I updated my answer

Comment: What i want is `io` should be stored when `socketCode.js` hit means from `app.js` file.

So when i call socketCode from app.js file. If i log console outside the test(directly inside module.exports) it get printed. Now that io instance should be propagate in test function too. and when i call test function it should use io object.

Comment: In a nutshell, Suppose i want to emit event from controller, routes, models. How can i do?

Comment: i would not have those parameters inside controllers and similar files.

Comment: If you can explain me what is the best way to send event from controller files.

Comment: Hm that's technically a different question. This project describes the usage of socket.io in express projects pretty well: https://github.com/onedesign/express-socketio-tutorial

Comment: Thanks @kentor, Yeah i knew this way. In that project, the `io` is bind with `res` object. But I doubt is this the best way to do so? That's why i was trying my own solution. I stuck since while. So i thought to ask here

Comment: What's wrong with it? You can still pass the io instance to your own module where you can put all your logic. Then your functions inside of your module would take the `io` object as parameter. In the route itself you simply call the function of your module along with the io object.

Comment: Okay/ I was not sure whether it is good to bind `io` with `res` object. and pass it to my own module where needed. But confusion was there. So according to you its okay to bind it with res right?

Comment: Yes it is okay, however you wouldn't pass the object to the module for initialization, but to the functions instead.

Comment: @MalikLakhani Can you accept the answer if your question is answered? So that others know your question has been answered :-).

Answer (score 0):

There is a library using the Typescript language that will help you to shorten the hard and long way , called [socket-controllers](https://github.com/typestack/socket-controllers)